# How to send Unity NetworkMessages

Tags: unity, multiplayer

So me and a couple of people are building a game with Unity, and I wanted to figure out how to keep the score in sync with all of the clients. After a lot of looking around on both the internet and the Unity API Docs, I found these things called NetworkMessages, However I do not know exactly what they do, or how to use/send/receive them. My first guess for what they were was, a simple way I could send any kind of data to all clients with them.

Please tell me if i'm right, if not what are they, and how would I go about using them to maybe keep the game score in sync with all of our clients.

Thanks!